Why wagmi with react returns object with numeric keys when fetch data from contract?
I have the issue that when I use useReadContract with abi , address an function name i receive the data like this: [{result: {0: value, 1: value}}]. The question is why this is possible when I have ABI with output names and how to fix it ?

Generate the ABI again and try again!
This error could be most likely due to incorrect ABI

I tried but the problem was not there . I upload also again the contract and try ,but again nothing. Is there possible way the error to be from versions of wagmi ,react,typescript??
